# Node Js Complex Design Principle (Promise, async/await)

Tags: node.js, async-await, project-structure

This is a common process for me in my previous works, so i usually have a very complex use case take for example

```
async function doThis(){
  for (100x) {
     try {
       insertToDatabase()
       await selectAndManipulateData()
       createEmailWorker()
       /** and many more **/
     } catch {
       logToAFile()
     }
  }
}
```

The code works, but its complicated 1 function doing all the things, the only reason i do this is because i can verify in real time if one function fails i can make sure the other function wont run so there wont be any incorrect data.

What i want to know is, what is the best architecture in defining a project structure that is not sacrificing the data integrity? (or is it already good enough?)

Answer (score 0):

```
const doThis = async() => {
  try {
     for (100x) {
       await insertToDatabase();
       await selectAndManipulateData();
       await createEmailWorker();
       /** and many more **/
     }
  }
  catch {
    await logToAFile();
  }
}
```

The best way of doing this is, you should always use await to call any function and make sure to with es6 syntax's as it gives a lot more feature. Your function  should always be an async.
Always put your loop in try catch as it will give you any error in catch and it will calling function specific.

Comment: you should also consider, throwing exceptions in case of failure in each of the three functions, so it breaks the loop

Comment: what about the loop? wont `await` block the other repetition to run ?

Comment: it will ofcourse 
then what you should think of is as follows 
you will save all entities 
use promise.All inside each function 
so while defining insertToDatabase , consider Promise.All for the loop inside, 
instead of defining the loop outside the three functions

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would separate the persistence, manipulation and email jobs. Consider storing your data is a single responsibility. In addition to this, your modification and email workers should work as scheduled jobs. Once the jobs triggered, they should check if there is data related to its responsibility.

Another way is changing these scheduled jobs with triggered jobs. You can build a chain of responsibility that triggers next jobs and they would decide to work or not.